# How do I export a package symbol to a namespace in Perl?

Tags: perl, module, export

I'm having trouble understanding how to export a package symbol to a namespace. I've followed the documentation almost identically, but it seems to not know about any of the exporting symbols.

**mod.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package mod;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT=qw($a);


our $a=(1);

1;
```

**test.pl**

```
$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use mod;

print($a);
```

This is the result of running it

```
$ ./test.pl
Global symbol "@ISA" requires explicit package name at mod.pm line 10.
Global symbol "@EXPORT" requires explicit package name at mod.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at ./test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 3.

$ perl -version
This is perl, v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int
```

Comment: Pretty ancient Perl. You'd better upgrade if you can.

Comment: legacy system, i'm stuck with it

Comment: The short version of the answers below is already explained in TFM: http://p3rl.org/Exporter#Good_Practices

Comment: $a (and $b) are not good variables to use. Same them for sort.

Comment: in production code i obviously use better names. for the purposes of this example i was trying to keep it simple

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not telling you that you're having a problem exporting `$a`. It's telling you that you're having a problem declaring `@ISA` and `@EXPORT`. `@ISA` and `@EXPORT` are package variables and under `strict`, they need to be declared with the `our` keyword (or imported from other modules--but that is not likely with those two). They are semantically different--but not functionally different--from `$a`.

**Nanny NOTE:** `@EXPORT` is not considered polite. Through [`Exporter`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) it dumps its symbols in the using package. Chances are if *you* think something is good to export--and it *is*--then it will be worth it for the user to request it. Use `@EXPORT_OK` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
package mod;                # Package name same as module.

use strict;
use warnings;

use base qw(Exporter);

our @ISA    = qw(Exporter); # Use our.
our @EXPORT = qw($z);       # Use our. Also $a is a bad variable name
                            # because of its special role for sort().

our $z = 1;

1;
```

Answer (score 7):

Others have correctly identified the problem and offered solutions.  I thought it would be useful to point out a debugging tip.  To isolate a problem to a given file, you can attempt to compile just that file using `perl -c`(refer to [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)):

```
perl -c mod.pm
```

This would have given you the same error message, leading you to realize the problem is in your `.pm` file, not your `.pl` file.